# In app purchase - bundling (apple)

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to, if someone makes an in-app purchase, generate a voucher code which would ultimately offer the a discount on another application?

IE: Does apple have a voucher system, other than the iTunes voucher. I've never noticed this possibility before.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not allow developers to offer something that would normally be purchased through iTunes. What you can do eventually is postpone the date of a recurrent purchase like a subscription (I'm not sure of this, check out iTunes rules). I didn't hear of any Apple voucher system, as you mention it.